# Loop through node reference

Tags: rules, nodes

I want to send emails using email stored on node fields that are referenced twice by other two contents types. I have this content types relationship:

```
Content1                 
field1 (unlimited) - reference > Content2    
                                 field2 (only 1) - reference > Content3
                                                               email
```

I want to send a email message to all itens on field1 using email field on Content3, after the node is created or updated.

I dont have experience with Rules looping. Ill appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Rules normally reacts to something happening (i.e. a new node is created) which then causes the email action. What will trigger this rule?

Comment: @longboardnode i know, it can be any...node update, node saved...thats not the problem...i got covered.

Comment: do you solve the problem? if you are still interested in this, let me know to start a bounty here ;-)

Comment: i found a workaround, but not a solution...any tips?

Comment: Content1, 2 and 3 are nodes of the same content type? Email should be sent when which Content is updated (1,2 or 3?).

Comment: test the answer and if this works for you, let me know

Comment: JoseSanPedro -- I'm with @oksana here: your description is too vague. what exactly is Type 1 and Type 2? Is Type 3 an email definition? If you make yourself more clear, I can probably tell you two different ways to solve your problem, using Views and Rules together, most likely.

Comment: @oksana-c the content types are differents for each content.

Comment: i tried to edit my post to improve the description but cant save. save button remains disabled.

Comment: @JoseSanPedro  The rule I created uses 3 different content types as well, have you tried using it? Btw, good work on your little scheme, made for a nice visual - so I just went with the most logical setup.

Comment: @oksana-c i just tested your answer and you nailed it! i reply to you below and marked the answer as accepted, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Rule will react on event "After updating existing content of type Content1".

The Rule will have to utilize a component in order to reach the email field in Content3.

In short: Rule loops through Content1 reference field (may contain multiple references) and then component will process each referenced node of type Content2 and return a variable back to the Rule. Returned variable contains an email that is taken from the field of the node of type Content3.

**STEP 1 - Create Rules Component** (export below)

```
{ "rules_process_content2_return_email" : {
    "LABEL" : "Process Referenced Content2 Entity and Return Email",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "content2" : { "label" : "Content2", "type" : "node" },
      "email_address" : { "label" : "Email Address", "type" : "text", "parameter" : false }
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "content2" ], "field" : "field_content_reference_2" } },
      { "entity_has_field" : {
          "entity" : [ "content2:field-content-reference-2" ],
          "field" : "field_email"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "variable_add" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "value" : [ "content2:field-content-reference-2:field-email" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "email_address" : "Email Address" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "email-address" ],
          "value" : [ "content2:field-content-reference-2:field-email" ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "PROVIDES VARIABLES" : [ "email_address" ]
  }
}
```

**STEP 2 - Create the Rule that uses Component above** (export below)

```
{ "rules_send_email" : {
    "LABEL" : "Send Email",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_update--content1" : { "bundle" : "content1" } },
    "DO" : [
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "node:field-content-reference" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "content2_item" : "Content2 item" },
          "DO" : [
            { "component_rules_process_content2_return_email" : {
                "USING" : { "content2" : [ "content2-item" ] },
                "PROVIDE" : { "email_address" : { "email_address" : "Email Address" } }
              }
            },
            { "mail" : {
                "to" : "[email-address:value]",
                "subject" : "Test Email on Content1 Update",
                "message" : "[node:title] was updated",
                "language" : [ "" ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Replace "content1", "content2" and machine names of fields with your own content/fields machine names before importing. Modify to your liking.

Comment: I'm trying to digest your answer, but I don't see any `3` in your answer, just content `1` and `2`. **is `content2:field-content-reference-2:field-email` the line that fetches content 3's e-mail?** in your component.

Comment: @NoSssweat that's right. Thanks for catching that, I just removed "content3" from the list of items to be replaced.

Comment: If they are different content types will this answer work?

Comment: Yes. The rule is specifically for 3 different content types as, if I understood correctly, that's what question called for.

Comment: I've never used the **Add a variable** action before. Pretty cool what it does! This is worth more than +50, I will re-bounty your answer once this bounty expires.

Comment: **PS:** when Add a variable, you need to click on the (switch to data selection button). Then and only then `content2:field-content-reference-2:field-email` will become available.

Comment: From Rules docs - _"direct input mode is most useful when entering a new text token, rather than another available data variable"_. You can still use chained objects in direct input mode, like `[content2:field-content-reference-2:field-email]`, if you know exactly what your field's machine name is. There is no reason to use direct input mode in rules when working with single variables,  but you'd really have to use direct input mode though is when e.g. constructing the content of the email body with tokens or displaying custom system messages to users.

Comment: @oksana-c you nailed it! i imported your component and managed to create the rule myself using the imported component, because when i tried to import your rule i was getting errors...i think the rule is missing the "node type" and "content has a field" conditions.

its working nice now...many thanks! ill extend this to load other fields from Content3 to use on the Rule!

Comment: @JoseSanPedro I'm glad it worked out for you

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit confused by your example -- it might help if you said what your content types represent -- but I can tell you in general how to do this.

Let's assume that you want to send your email whenever a Content Type 3 is created or updated.  I'm going to guess that Content Type 3 defines the content of an email somehow (i.e., data like the title from the email will be used in the email).

I'm also going to assume that somehow (again, a clearer example would help) that somehow, Content Type 1 and Content Type 2 define an email list to send to.

For your example to work at all, somehow your Type 3, when it changes, needs to have a field that somehow points back to your email list.  Let's say that one of your types is an "email group", and one of your types are the emails that belong to each group (this is why we need you to be more clear). Then:

- You make a rule that triggers on the update and create events of the node.
- Using data selectors, you create an action loop under actions.  Rules data selectors "drill down" into a data type. Since the update and create events get passed the node object, you'll see a "node" item. If you start selecting that node, the selectors will show you all of the node's fields. You want to select the multivalued field that points to, say, the email groups the message wants to send to. Now you have a loop that will take that field and go over each individual slot in that multi-valued field.
- Add an action to the loop (it's in the middle of the window in small print), OR add a sub-loop that goes from your Type 2 to your Type 1 (whatever makes sense in your example).
- The action of the inner loop is sending email. You can fill in the fields of the email using data selectors that pull the email fields from the node or one of the sub-items that you created from your loop(s). Note that you can also add tokens into your emails from the "Replacement Patterns" listed under each parameter of the emails.

This is a bit vague. If you'll make your example more concrete, I can make the answer more specific.

You can also send emails using Views Bulk Operations and Rules. But this does not appear to be what you want.

Comment: I don't think this is what he is looking for, but +1 for your effort.

Comment: @NoSssweat -- what do you think he wants? I'm confused :-)

Comment: If you look at the graph he drew: He has cType#1 (node 1) which has an entity reference field with unlimited values. In that field he is referencing 2 nodes. ex: hello (2), world (3) <-- both of these are cType#2. In hello (node 2) he has an entity reference of max 1 value. ex: cool (4). Cool (node 4) has an e-mail field. So he wants when he creates a cType#1 (node 1) an e-mail gets sent to the address in e-mail field of cType#3 (cool node 4). [oksana-c has the correct answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185149/loop-through-node-reference/188885?noredirect=1#answer-188858)

Comment: Basically he is referencing a node, which in turn is referencing another node, which is referencing another node that has an e-mail address.